SQL query for partitioning by one column based on condition
I have the following table t1:
STATE   SAUCE     type    VALUE
Normal  Yum Yum   bowl    4.5
Normal  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
Normal  Indomie   cup     3.5
Redo1   Indomie   pack1   15.0
Redo1   Indomie   pack2   5.0
Redo2   Mayo      pack3   5.0

And I'm looking for an output table that has rows such that:

For SAUCE values that have rows with both STATE=NORMAL and STATE=REDO ->  only use all rows with STATE=Redo and remove all rows for that SAUCE with STATE=NORMAL.
For SAUCE values that only have rows with STATE=NORMAL -> include all those rows.

Applying the above 2 rules to the table t1 above, following is the expected output:
STATE   SAUCE     type    VALUE
Normal  Yum Yum   bowl    4.5
Normal  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
Redo1   Indomie   pack1   15.0
Redo1   Indomie   pack2   5.0
Redo2   Mayo      pack3   5.0

The closest I came to the above output is with the query:
DB Fiddle
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT 'Normal' AS STATE, 'Yum Yum' AS SAUCE, 'bowl'  AS type, 4.5 AS VALUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Normal', 'Yum Yum', 'cup', 4.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Normal', 'Indomie', 'cup', 3.5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Redo1', 'Indomie', 'pack1', 15.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Redo1', 'Indomie', 'pack2', 5.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Redo2', 'Mayo', 'pack3', 5.0
)
, row_num AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SAUCE ORDER BY STATE DESC) AS rank
  FROM t1
)
SELECT *
FROM row_num
WHERE rank=1

which gave the output:
STATE   SAUCE     type    VALUE
Normal  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
Redo1   Indomie   pack2   5.0
Redo2   Mayo      pack3   5.0

Which is missing 2 rows.
Would there be a SQL query for getting the expected output?

What is the significance of there being REDO1 and REDO2?  What should happen if both redo values are present?

If both values are present, then use the value from REDO2. Which is why ordering by SAUCE DESC helps with DENSE_RANK().

You should be able to just substitute DENSE_RANK() for ROW_NUMBER(). This will get you the output you were looking for. You were very close :).
Example:
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT 'Normal' AS STATE, 'Yum Yum' AS SAUCE, 'bowl'  AS type, 4.5 AS VALUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Normal', 'Yum Yum', 'cup', 4.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Normal', 'Indomie', 'cup', 3.5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Redo1', 'Indomie', 'pack1', 15.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Redo1', 'Indomie', 'pack2', 5.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Redo2', 'Mayo', 'pack3', 5.0
)
select x.[STATE], x.SAUCE, x.[type], x.[VALUE]
from
(
    select dense_rank() over(partition by sauce order by [STATE] desc) as rnk, *
    from t1
) x
where x.rnk = 1
order by [STATE], SAUCE desc, [type]

Results:



STATE
SAUCE
type
VALUE




Normal
Yum Yum
bowl
4.5


Normal
Yum Yum
cup
4.0


Redo1
Indomie
pack1
15.0


Redo1
Indomie
pack2
5.0


Redo2
Mayo
pack3
5.0



The difference is how they increment. DENSE_RANK() increments only when the values in the ORDER BY clause in the window function change (i.e. value in next row in the partition differs from the last), whereas ROW_NUMBER() increments once for every row within the partition, regardless.

The data already has Redo1 and Redo2

@MatBailie thanks, you're completely correct, I was overthinking for a second there. The caveat made no sense, so I've removed it.
